# How can I configure Sonata Admin form to handle Enum types in a 'json' column for a User table?

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony6

1. User table with 'roles' column with type json (roles - longtext - not null - comment '(DC2Type:json)');
2. Trying to save User via Sonata Admin tool and get the error `Expected argument of type "array", "App\\UserModule\\Entity\\Enum\\UserRole" given at property path "roles"`.

   ```
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form): void
   {
       $form->add('roles', EnumType::class, ['class' => UserRole::class]);
   }
   ```

[image]

Form field is correctly displayed, but handling post request -  got error. Creating user via console command works nice, so this is only about Sonata stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way it can be done - use ChoiceType with 'multiple' setting

```
        $form->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $roles,
        'multiple' => true
    ]);
```